# IP restriction for a certain domain if multiple domains point to same webroot (.htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess

Normally I create IP restrictions with adding following snippet in .htaccess:

```
 <Limit GET POST>
 order deny,allow
 deny from all
 allow from 23.98.431.9
 allow from 123.456.78.9
 allow from 9.876.54.32
 allow from 555.333.2.33
</Limit>
```

Above snippet works perfectly if only one domain is pointing to webroot. But how can I add an IP restriction for only one domain if multiple domains point to the same webroot? For example:

> www.example.com
>
> wwww.examplewebsite.com
>
> wwww.exampleawesome.com

All above domains are pointing to the same webroot. But now I need to restrict access for only www.example.com (certain IPs are allowed to see the site). How can I achieve this?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mod_rewrute` rules for this in root .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(GET|POST)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^(23\.98\.431\.9|123\.456\.78\.9|9\.876\.54\.32|555\.333\.2\.33)$
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: Wow, I'm really impressed...you seem to know everything about rewrites. Works perfectly of course. Thank you so much!